# Youtube session token

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, youtube-api

Is the youtube session token unique for each user or for each login process ?
I am using Zend with youtube API

```
  $_SESSION['sessionToken'] = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);
```

and how can I get the user info such as email, full name etc using this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Session token is per login session.
- Full name and other profile data is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles) if they filled it in.
- And you don't have access to e-mails and passwords, obviously.

That's about it.